# Get count of unique values with the column name in Laravel 5.2 Collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I am trying to get the number of unique Brands from my Products Table with their count from a Laravel collection.

I was able to do that using a specific query for the products but the reason i'm using a collection now is because i also want to get the Product Origins (Country), Conditions (Used / New) of the products and i thought it would be much better to use a collection from one query rather than have three separate queries for each data.

The code below works but it doesn't show the count for each unique Brand.

Here is the Table
[image]

Here is my Controller

```
$products = DB::table('products')
 ->select('products.*')
 ->whereNull('products.deleted_at')
 ->get();

$BrandCollection = collect($products);
$Brands = $BrandCollection->unique('Brand')->sortBy('Brand')->keyBy('Brand')->pluck('Brand');
```

**So, the result i'm looking for is**

HP 3
Toshiba 2
Lenovo 1

I thought it could be done using concat for the collection but since i'm on Laravel 5.2, i'm looking for other solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you really want to use collections (not Eloquent) you can do it like this:

```
$brandsWithCount = $BrandCollection->groupBy('Brand')->map(function($values) {
    return $values->count();
})->sort()->reverse();
```

For example if you set `$brandCollection` like this:

```
$BrandCollection = collect([
    ['Brand' => 'HP'],
    ['Brand' => 'HP'],
    ['Brand' => 'HP'],
    ['Brand' => 'Toshiba'],
    ['Brand' => 'Toshiba'],
    ['Brand' => 'Lenovo'],
]);
```

result will be:

```
Collection {#372
  #items: array:3 [
    "HP" => 3
    "Toshiba" => 2
    "Lenovo" => 1
  ]
}
```

as expected.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm.

Comment: How would you apply sorting? Coz- sort('Brand)->reverse() doesn't work

Comment: @user3659497 It's working for me, have you verified it? `sort` should sort ascending and `reverse` will reverse the order

Comment: Don't know why but it didn't work, i added the sorting before the groupBy and removed the last ->sort()->reverse() and it's working now.  $Brands = $BrandCollection->sortBy('Brand')->groupBy('Brand')->map(function($values) {
    return $values->count();
});   Thanks

Comment: So the above code works perfectly and I can `dd()` the collection in my view, but I can't figure out how to display the end result in a table, since a `@foreach` loop just presents the numeric values. I need to display name-value pairs. How did you display your results from the collection generated above?

Comment: You just saved me hours of work :) I salute you

Answer (score 1):

There is a Collection Helper called CountBy, does exactly what you need.

[Collections CountBy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-countBy)

```
$BrandCollection->countBy('Brand');
```

It will retourn as expected

```
#items: array:3 [
    "HP" => 3
    "Toshiba" => 2
    "Lenovo" => 1
  ]
```

Simple :D